# Which is the dependent variable?

Tags: r, regression, python, linear

I was looking at this [Data Science question on TestDome](https://www.testdome.com/questions/data-science/marketing-costs/19228?visibility=1&skillId=28).

The problems is stated as the following:

> Implement the desired_marketing_expenditure function, which returns
>   the required amount of money that needs to be invested in a new
>   marketing campaign to sell the desired number of units.
>
> Use the data from previous marketing campaigns to evaluate how the
>   number of units sold grows linearly as the amount of money invested
>   increases.
>
> For example, for the desired number of 60,000 units sold and previous
>   campaign data from the table below, the function should return the
>   float 250,000.

Approaching this with linear regression I see this as:

`marketing_expenditure = coeff * units_sold + intercept + error`

because what I'm trying to find is the `marketing expenditure` given a number of `units sold`.

However the author of this test seems it has seen the `marketing expenditure` as the independent variable, in other words:

`units_sold = coeff * marketing_expenditure + intercept + error`

from which then it calculates the `marketing_expenditure` by rearranging the equation.

The two approaches are not equivalent and give different results as depending on what is the dependent / independent variable the linear regression algorithm tries to minimise different square distances to different regression lines.

Which approach is correct and why?

Comment: In a cause-and-effect relationship, units sold will not directly cause marketing expenditures. That is, marketing expenditures are not directly dependent on units sold.

Comment: Thanks @JamesPhillips, I see your point but for what I read about Linear Regression, LR is not trying to explain causality but mainly correlation. In fact one could find a correlation between chocolate consumption and Nobel prizes but that does not mean that there is a causality. In that light, one would fit a Linear Regression based on what one wants to predict not what causes what. Am I wrong?

Comment: Absent its context, this question is difficult to parse.  It *sounds* like it might be asking you to implement an [inverse regression](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=calibration%20inverse%20regression%20score%3a1) but without the author recognizing that to be the case.

Comment: However the author of this test seems it has seen the marketing expenditure as the independent variable, in other words:

units_sold = coeff * marketing_expenditure + intercept + error

from which then it calculates the  marketing_expenditure by rearranging the equation.

Comment: However the author of this test seems it has seen the marketing expenditure as the independent variable, in other words:

units_sold = coeff * marketing_expenditure + intercept + error

from which then it calculates the  marketing_expenditure. This is self-propagated idea without reasoning . Moreover no assumptions that invoke statistics are pointed. No definition of terms including error term

Comment: Introducing intercept as well as error term in a single model like the proposed one should cause confusion because error term is traditionally used in linear modelling and interecept term is used to indicate regression-based modelling. I am not aware of idiosyncratic models that  can be constructed to meet a situation.

Comment: I’m surprised no one has pointed out that marketing spend is not a random variable in this context.

Answer (score 1):

> Implement the desired_marketing_expenditure function, which returns the required amount of money that needs to be invested in a new marketing campaign to sell the desired number of units.

You know what? Let's implement that function. I will use Python.

Import libraries

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn import linear_model
```

Use the data

```
mark_exp = np.array([300000, 200000, 400000, 300000, 100000]).reshape(-1, 1)
units_s = np.array([60000, 50000, 90000, 80000, 30000]).reshape(-1, 1)
```

First, a linear regression like this: `units_sold = coeff * marketing_expenditure + intercept`

```
lin_regr = linear_model.LinearRegression()
lin_regr.fit(mark_exp, units_s)

print(lin_regr.score(mark_exp, units_s)) # 0.91
print(lin_regr.coef_) # 0.2
print(lin_regr.intercept_) # 10_000
print(lin_regr.predict(np.array(60_000).reshape(-1, 1))) # 22_000
```

Well, that number is wrong, just what I expected. The input number is $60\,000$ and the function returns $22\,000$.

Second, a linear regression like this: `marketing_expenditure = coeff * units_sold + intercept`

```
lin_regr2 = linear_model.LinearRegression()
lin_regr2.fit(units_s, mark_exp)

print(lin_regr2.score(units_s, mark_exp)) # 0.91
print(lin_regr2.coef_) # 4.56
print(lin_regr2.intercept_) # -22_807.01
print(lin_regr2.predict(np.array(60_000).reshape(-1, 1)) # 250_877.19
```

I like this. The input number is $60\,000$ and the function returns $250\,877$. What did I assume? That `marketing_expenditure` is the dependent variable and `units_sold` is the independent variable, just what you said in your question. What do I want to predict? $Z$. So let $Z$ be the dependent variable.

However, the confusion... the damn confusion is present because the guy does something neither you or I would do. Let me give an example.

Suppose that I give two lists of numbers, one labeled `time` with $t_1, t_2, \dots, t_{10}$ as the numbers and the other labeled `velocity` with $v_1, v_2, \dots, v_{10}$ as the numbers. Each pair $(t_i, v_i)$ is measured in an experiment and I tell you that the relationship between both variables is

$$v = a\cdot t + b. \tag{1}$$

The goal is to find $a$ and $b$ with linear regression. You and I naturally assume that $t$ is the independent variable and $v$ is the dependent variable. Say you find $a = 2.5$ and $b = 1.3$ (with the correct units, but we don't care for the moment). Then I tell you that find $t$ given $v = 4.8$, what would you do? Rearrange the equation?

$$\dfrac{1}{a} v - \dfrac{b}{a} = t \tag{2}$$
$$ c \cdot v + d = t, \quad \text{with} \quad c=\dfrac{1}{a}, d = \dfrac{-b}{a} \tag{3} $$

Do a linear regression to find $c$ and $d$? Did I tell you that if you want to predict $t$, $t$ is the dependent variable? I will not tell you why $(1)$ feels more natural, maybe because there are historical reasons [[citation needed]](https://xkcd.com/285/) or maybe time is viewed as the independent variable when you include distance, or speed, or acceleration, or force, etc... [[citation needed]](https://xkcd.com/285/). By the way, in $(1)$, $a$ is acceleration and $b$ is the initial speed; in $(3)$, $c$ and $d$ are...

> Which approach is correct and why?

I am with you, if you want to predict `marketing_expenditure`, `marketing_expenditure` is the dependent variable (besides, with Python it's easier than the other option). There must be strong reasons (other than casuality) to change the order of the variables, I don't see those in this example.

Answer (score 0):

The questions in the first highlighted section call for you to do both - and also maybe neither!

> Implement the desired_marketing_expenditure function, which returns
>   the required amount of money that needs to be invested in a new
>   marketing campaign to sell the desired number of units.

This is very poorly worded. To me, "implement a function" doesn't call for regression at all. It sounds like there is an already existing function, and you should just do something with it. However, if regression is called for, then it seems like number of units is the DV. That is, to me, also strange. You can't manipulate the number of units sold, you can manipulate the amount spent, but the way it's worded, it looks like they want you to do it that way.

> Use the data from previous marketing campaigns to evaluate how the
>   number of units sold grows linearly as the amount of money invested
>   increases.

This clearly does call for linear regression, but here the DV is clearly number of units.

So, what to do? Can you contact the people who wrote TestDome? Can you ignore this?